# Data tabs prev/next button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tabs

I have some tabs.. and arrows next/prev. I would like to switch tabs with arrows. But I'm not sure how to do it. I have no idea how to do this. I have fixed numbers 1,2,3,4 ..

```js
$("[data-tabs][data-show]").on("click", function() {
  var name = $(this).attr("data-tabs");
  var id = $(this).attr("data-show");

  var tabs = $("[data-tabs=\"" + name + "\"][data-id]");
  tabs.removeClass("active");
  tabs.filter("[data-id=\"" + id + "\"]").addClass("active");

  var buttons = $("[data-tabs=\"" + name + "\"][data-show]");
  buttons.removeClass("active");
  buttons.filter("[data-show=\"" + id + "\"]").addClass("active");

  var prev = $("[data-tabs-prev]");
  var next = $("[data-tabs-next]");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs__prev" data-tabs-prev>PREV</div>
<div class="tabs__next" data-tabs-next>NEXT</div>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tabs__item active" data-tabs="demo" data-show="1">Test1</li>
  <li class="tabs__item" data-tabs="demo" data-show="2">Test 2</li>
  <li class="tabs__item" data-tabs="demo" data-show="3">Test 3</li>
  <li class="tabs__item" data-tabs="demo" data-show="4">Test 4</li>
  <li class="tabs__item" data-tabs="demo" data-show="5">Test 5</li>
</ul>

<div class="show">
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="1" class="show__item active">Content</div>
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="2" class="show__item active">Content</div>
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="3" class="show__item active">Content</div>
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="4" class="show__item active">Content</div>
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="5" class="show__item active">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please create a [mcve] from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let index = 1;
$("[data-tabs][data-show]").on("click", function () {
    var name = $(this).attr("data-tabs");
    var id = $(this).attr("data-show");
    controlTab(name, id)
});

$("[data-tabs-prev]").on("click", function () {
    index = index > 1 ? index - 1 : index
    controlTab('demo', index)

});
$("[data-tabs-next]").on("click", function () {
    index = index < $("[data-tabs=demo][data-show]").length ? index + 1 : index
    controlTab('demo', index)
});

function controlTab(name, id) {
    index = +id
    var tabs = $("[data-tabs=\"" + name + "\"][data-id]");
    tabs.removeClass("active");
    tabs.filter("[data-id=\"" + id + "\"]").addClass("active");

    var buttons = $("[data-tabs=\"" + name + "\"][data-show]");
    buttons.removeClass("active");
    buttons.filter("[data-show=\"" + id + "\"]").addClass("active");

}
```

```css
.tabs .active {
    color:red;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.show .show__item {
    display:none;
}
.show .active {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs__prev" data-tabs-prev>PREV</div>
<div class="tabs__next" data-tabs-next>NEXT</div>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tabs__item active" data-tabs="demo" data-show="1">Test1</li>
  <li class="tabs__item" data-tabs="demo" data-show="2">Test 2</li>
  <li class="tabs__item" data-tabs="demo" data-show="3">Test 3</li>
  <li class="tabs__item" data-tabs="demo" data-show="4">Test 4</li>
  <li class="tabs__item" data-tabs="demo" data-show="5">Test 5</li>
</ul>

<div class="show">
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="1" class="show__item active">Content2</div>
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="2" class="show__item ">Content23</div>
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="3" class="show__item ">Content245453</div>
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="4" class="show__item ">Content4534</div>
  <div data-tabs="demo" data-id="5" class="show__item ">Content45</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.